# Problems implementing setOnKeyListener

Tags: java, android

I got some android dev homework and I'm trying to add a setOnKeyListener to calculate and convert some numbers when I press the enter key on the keyboard. I already made the button listener and it works smoothly but the key listener doesn't. Here's the code...

```
         inputuser.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                final int spinnerPosition = mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

                calculo(spinnerPosition);
                return false;

            }
        });


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final int spinnerPosition = mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                calculo(spinnerPosition);

            }
        });
```

Both Listeners call a method named "calculo" which makes the numbers and set a text view visible and passes to the text the result of the calculation.

```
public void calculo(int spinnerPosition){
        String value= inputuser.getText().toString();
        int inputUser = Integer.parseInt(value);

        double operacion = 0;


        if (spinnerPosition == 0){

            operacion = inputUser * valoresDeConversion[0];
            String result = String.valueOf(operacion);

            resultado.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            resultado.setText(result);
        }else if (spinnerPosition == 1){
            operacion = inputUser * valoresDeConversion[1];
            String result = String.valueOf(operacion);
            resultado.setText(result);
            resultado.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }else if (spinnerPosition == 2){
            operacion = inputUser * valoresDeConversion[2];
            String result = String.valueOf(operacion);
            resultado.setText(result);
            resultado.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else if (spinnerPosition == 3){
            operacion = inputUser / valoresDeConversion[0];
            String result = String.valueOf(operacion);
            resultado.setText(result);
            resultado.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else if (spinnerPosition == 4){
            operacion = inputUser / valoresDeConversion[1];
            String result = String.valueOf(operacion);
            resultado.setText(result);
            resultado.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else if (spinnerPosition == 5){
            operacion = inputUser / valoresDeConversion[2];
            String result = String.valueOf(operacion);
            resultado.setText(result);
            resultado.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

And here's my XML code

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/valor"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:entries="@array/valor"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultado"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />
```

The app brokes when I enter a value in the edit text or when I press the button and I'm not getting where's the issue

(Edit)

Here's the message of the Logcat

```
                                                                                                                                    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: myapplication2, PID: 3883
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
    at MainActivity.calculo(MainActivity.java:85)
    at MainActivity$1.onKey(MainActivity.java:61)
     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:13348)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1922)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1922)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1922)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1922)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1922)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1922)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:453)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1839)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3953)
    at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:122)
    at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:84)
    at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:140)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:569)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3054)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:367)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5413)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5281)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4841)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4947)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4815)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5004)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4841)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4815)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7505)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7474)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7435)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:4561)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Which error do you get? How do you initialize `mySpinner`?

Comment: It would be useful to provide the exact error message displayed in console during app crash

Comment: Right, I already edited the question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` - your `String` is empty (no text in `EditText`), so it can't be parsed, it isn't a number

check if `String value` isn't `null` or empty, like this

```
String value = inputuser.getText().toString();
if(value==null || value.length()==0) return;
```

or more universal way

```
String value;
int inputUser;
try{
    value= inputuser.getText().toString();
    inputUser = Integer.parseInt(value);
} catch(Exception ignored){
    return;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, now I can add numbers what when I press the button nothing appears. BTW, I have the XML edit text in "number" input-type                                                                   
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/valor"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        />

Comment: so you have some bug in logic of not-posted code. when you pressing button what do you have inside your `EditText`?

Comment: @Sergio you should post your xml sources in question itself. However, your original question is answered

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried the second way just adding

```
//String value; I didn't use these variables
//int inputUser;

final int spinnerPosition = mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        inputuser.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                try{
                    calculo(spinnerPosition);
                } catch(Exception ignored){
                    return false;
                }
                return false;

            }
        });
```

And it works perfect, but I don't really understand well why.

Here's my XML code

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/valor"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:entries="@array/valor"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultado"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />
```